# Database testing in Selenium

Tags: java, database

I have a question like i have multiple tables in database and I'm fetching data from the db.
So for one table i would fetch record and save it in a list and use it.

So if i have more than one tables in my database shall i keep on storing them in different Result set objects and creating new list for every table accordingly?Also do i have use another loop for second result set object (rs1) as shown below:

```
ResultSet rs=stm.executeQuery("select * from logincred"); Table 1
ResultSet rs1=stm.executeQuery("select * from home");     Table 2


ResultSetMetaData metadata=rs.getMetaData();
            int colCount=metadata.getColumnCount();
            System.out.println(colCount);

            while(rs.next()){
                for(int i=1;i<=colCount;i++){       
                    String result=rs.getString(i);
                    System.out.println(result + " : ");
                    listOfLoginCred.add(result);
                    System.out.println(listOfLoginCred);
                }

            }
```

Comment: What this got to do with Selenium?

Comment: i m using all the test data from db and using it my scripts